# Reload table data only if cold launch or settings change

Tags: swift, swiftui, nsuserdefaults, swiftui-list

I have a simple two tabbed app which I'm trying to manage when or if the `List` reloads data from the network.

I want to have the app only reload data when:

- cold booting first time (closed state to launch);
- going from `.background` to `.active` state; or
- toggling a setting in the `SettingsView()`

I don't want the `List` to reload if going to the `SettingsView()` without toggling an option or just switching tabs in general.

```swift
// tab view
struct Tabs: View {
 var body: some View {
  TabView {
   ViewOne().tabItem { Label("Settings", systemImage: "gear") }
   ViewTwo().tabItem { Label("List", systemImage: "bag") }
  }
 }
}

// ViewOne
struct ViewOne: View {
 var body: some View {
  Text("View one: Settings")
  // toggles and options here
   .onChange(of: option) { value in
    // do other things here
    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "reloadList")
   }
 }
}

// ViewTwo
struct ViewTwo: View {
 var body: some View {
 List(arrayItems) { item in
 }
  .onAppear {
   if( UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "reloadList") ) {
    reloadData()
    UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "reloadList")
   }
  }
 }
}
```

The above works when running the app and I toggle settings - the `UserDefaults` triggers the `reloadData()` function. This also solves my dilemma of switching tabs (without setting changes) and not reloading data.

However, I've now shot myself in the foot with a terrible UX since the table doesn't fetch data on launch - cold or background.

I tried adding another `UserDefaults.standard.set(true, "coldLaunch")` to the `Tabs` view which would then set the `reloadList` to `true` but that wasn't triggering until the tab was switched and then back again.

I have also tried setting or triggering the `reloadData()` from `@Environment(\.scenePhase) var scenePhase` but that then triggers on every launch alike `onAppear`.

Maybe I'm not thinking straight, but I'm trying to figure out the right flow on effect yet cant!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this the best as I could and thought I'd have it here for other users who may want to find a way of doing this in their apps.

In the TabView:

```swift
struct Tabs: View {
 @Environment(\.scenePhase) private var scenePhase
 var body: some View {
  TabView {
   ViewOne().tabItem { Label("Settings", systemImage: "gear") }
   ViewTwo().tabItem { Label("List", systemImage: "bag") }
  }

  // -- when the view is active reload the table
  .onChange(of: scenePhase) { phase in
   if( phase == .active ) {
    reloadData()
   }
  }

 }
}
```

Then on the other view which is to reload too add in the `.onAppear` code:

```swift
.onAppear {
 if( UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "reloadList") ) {
  reloadData()
  UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "reloadList")
 }
}
```

Where the `UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "reloadList")` is set to `true` from a change in the other view.

There are some issues based on when the app becomes `inactive` but due to the way the structure of iOS, there isn't any way to isolate `inactive` without accessing `active / background` states too.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> 1. cold booting first time (closed state to launch);
> 2. going from .background to .active state; or
> 3. toggling a setting in the SettingsView()
> ```

For Cold Booting:
You can try using this https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622944-willenterforegroundnotification or possibly even just putting the `reload()` within `viewDidLoad()` since that's called the very first time the app starts.

```
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(appToForeground), name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)

@objc func appToForeground(_ notification: Notification) {
    print("appToForeground ")

}
```

For toggling a setting in SettingsView(), I am using Notification Center as well. Something along these lines

Within your `viewDidLoad()` of your 1st Tab, you set up an observer

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                       selector: #selector(self.refreshTable),
                                       name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "newDataNotif"),
                                       object: nil)

 

    @objc func refreshTable() {
      reloadData()
      self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Then on your 2nd Tab, when there is a change in your settings and you want to reload the table in the 1st tab, this is what you do.

eg:

```
  user.setting.changed = true
  NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "newDataNotif"), object: nil)
```

this notification will be posted once there is a change in your settings, and then the `observer` you placed in the 1st tab will pick up the notification, and then it will call the `@objc func refreshTable()`
and then your table will get refreshed.